# Calculate same etag in javascript as nginx

Tags: javascript, nginx, etag

I have a setup where images are rendered on a just-in-time fashion in nodejs. Afterwards the images are cached in a directory from where nginx will fetch them directly on subsequent requests.

How do I produce the same etag in nodejs/javascript as nginx will produce on the second request?

Comment: How about after you create the image in node, instead of returning the image to the client, you load into Nginx directory and have your node server redirect to the Nginx resource?

Comment: It's not a bad idea but another HTTP request is nearly as expensive as just letting the user request the image again on the next pageload.

Comment: If you know C, you can take this apart: https://github.com/mikewest/nginx-static-etags/blob/master/ngx_http_static_etags_module.c

Comment: Keep in mind that a poorly implemented etag is more harmful than the extra HTTP request

Comment: @jibsales, I guess worst case is the etag won't be identical and the user would have to download the image twice (first from node, then from nginx)? I don't do C but I'll try reading it anyway, thanks.

Comment: @ThomasJensen for skipping an additional HTTP request you can use so called "internal redirect" http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal - so instead of returning the image from nodejs to the client, you load it into Nginx directory and have your node use "X-Accel-Redirect" to the Nginx "internal" hadler that will serve the file with etag.

Answer (score 0):

I had a thought. You could setup `nginx` to use `try_files` to first check if the file exists in the static directory and if not, proxy to node for creation. This is not exactly what you are looking for, but it will allow the browser to cache a consistent URL and then etag isn't as important.

```
location / {
    root /path/to/root/of/static/files;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @nodeserver;

    expires max;
    access_log off;
}

location @nodserver {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly how I do it today, but I would still like the etag in the first response as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer outlining how nginx calculates etag: https://serverfault.com/questions/690341/algorithm-behind-nginx-etag-generation

basically

```
etag = sprintf("%xT-%xO", file.last_modified_time, content_length)
```

You can repeat that in js using sprintf-js, but you'll need to know the file's last_modified_time before nginx caches it, and this is IMO impossible.

Comment: So it might be better to use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545567/calculate-same-etag-in-javascript-as-nginx/51323978#comment89622815_20545567